# Updated Parse SDK, getting " 'init()' is unavailable" for PFFile

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I just updated the Parse SDK and I'm getting a bunch of errors now. Where I declared "var myIcon = PFFile()", now I'm getting an error that says " 'init()' is unavailable". Anyone encounter this, how do I initialize these variables? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize a PFFile instance with some data. You can use any of the class methods found [here](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html).

For example, `PFFile(data: YOUR_NSDATA)`